# Files.copy method works unproperly

Tags: image, file, javafx, stream, copy

I tried to retrieve the image from database and add it to class Person. I copied image by Files.copy() to new image file and set new Image object. But it seems like all the process of every copying started firstly, so all the Image objects have got only one image - the last copied image, nevertheless copy() method stands before to setting. How to fix it?

```
try {
    checkConnection();
    rs = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Staff").executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
        InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("Photo");
        Files.copy(is, Paths.get("src\\ilc\\images\\image.jpg"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Image image = new Image("ilc/images/image.jpg", 100, 100, true, true);

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        persons.add(
                new Person(rs.getString("Name"), 
                           rs.getInt("Salary"),
                           rs.getDouble("Influence"),
                           false,
                           false,
                           false,
                           image)
        );
    }

    rs.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: why don't u want to create Image with InputStream that you have after `InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("Photo");` ? you would not need to use `Files.copy`  at all.

Comment: YOU ARE GENIUS MAN! IT WORKS! THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D

Comment: great, glad it worked. I posted it as an answer so we could close your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the solution is not to use `Files.copy` at all and create the `Image` using `InputStream` directly:

```
InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("Photo");
Image image = new Image(is, 100, 100, true, true);
...
```